# How can text be placed at the top line of the Bash terminal and held stationary while other commands are run?

Tags: bash, text, line

Let's say I want some text displayed at the top line of the Bash terminal -- perhaps the text is the current directory and the current time, kept current all the time. How could I generate this line and keep it updating in place while being able to run other commands?

Comment: `screen` or `tmux` come to mind.

Comment: I had in mind something like ```curses```, but I'm not sure.